# objective-c: access outlet with string containing its name

Tags: objective-c

I have IBOutlets named for example: outlet1, outlet2, outlet3. I want to access this outlets using @"outlet%d" where %d is value of variable. Is it possible?

Comment: Why not? Did you try it yourself?

Comment: @NR4TR: If he knew how to, he would have. The solution didn't occur to me at first as well, and I do have some Objective-C experience.

Comment: Sometimes it's much faster to try then to ask. It seems that @Denis Mikhaylov didn't try it.

Comment: @NR4TR: why so serious? How do u think i could try it? [object.@"outlet%d"]?? You should have look at Abizern answer. He makes profit, u'r not!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you try:

```
[myClass valueForKey:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"outlet%d", i]];
```

Have a look at the [Key Value Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/cocoa/Conceptual/KeyValueCoding/KeyValueCoding.html%23//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000107i)

Comment: I'm glad it helped. If it answered your question you could accept the answer (by clicking on the tick mark to the side) and/or upvoting it.